# Can't bind angular2 directive on native element

Tags: angular

I try to create a simple angular2 component, and I have an error when binding directive to a native DOM element.

For example:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/_custom.d.ts" />

import { Component, View } from 'angular2/angular2';
import { RouterLink } from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    directives: [RouterLink]
})

@View({
    template: `
        <a [router-link]="['/page']">test</a>
    `
})

export class MyComponent {    }
```

=> Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of the '<a>' element and there are no matching directives with a corresponding property.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Hey @tzi The `directives` property must go in the `View` annotation.

Comment: Thanks @EricMartinez. -_-\/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- As @EricMartinez said, "directives" is a "View" property
- As @dSebastien said, "router-link" became "routerLink"
- As @pardeep-jain said, "angular2/angular2" became "angular2/core", "View" annotation is being removed, no need of the typings line

Here is the right code:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { RouterLink } from 'angular2/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    directives: [RouterLink],
    template: `
        <a [routerLink]="['/page']">test</a>
    `
})

export class MyComponent {    }
```

Comment: Note that with the beta, router-link becomes routerLink (same for ngFor, ngIf, ...)

Answer (score 1):

As of Angular2 is in beta now so there are lot of changes has been made few of them here regarding this question may help to someone.

- `import { Component, View } from 'angular2/angular2'`

  changed to `import {Component, View } from 'angular2/core'`
  for list of all imports according to beta see here
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34697758/5043867

(in most cases there is no need to use view annotation because all the functionality of view annotation is gets included in Component annotation).

- no need to write typings line on the top of component because typing are included by default by angular team
  https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-alpha42-2015-10-13
- `router-link` changed to `routerLink`

Comment: `@View()` annotation is being removed.